# Why didn't Thor or Captain America just put Mjolnir on Thanos's chest or foot?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Since only those who are worthy are able to lift Mjolnir (as established in Avengers 1 and 2), why couldn't Thor or Captain America in *Avengers: Endgame* just put Mjolnir down on a part of Thanos (e.g. hand, foot, chest), preventing him from moving?

Comment: Because that requires having him staying still first?

Comment: However, in the Battle on Titan in Avengers: Infinity War, Spiderman, Dr. Strange, Iron Man, Drax, and Mantis had him bound and at their mercies even with four of the six stones. Surely they could have done so again with him having none of the stones and Thor sneaking up and dropping the hammer on him :D

Comment: "the Space Stone grants the wielder absolute control over space itself. It is primarily used to open portals to other locations and can even allow interdimensional travel." – [marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Space_Stone#Capabilities)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Thanos is never incapacitated long enough

During the fight with Captain America and Thor, Thanos is either on the attack or is  never down long enough for Mjolnir to be *placed* anywhere.

Even when Captain America calls down lightning and floors Thanos for a second. At this point Cap attempts to (ahem) hammer Thanos by bringing Mjolnir down on his chest but Thanos *just rolls out of the way*.

Basically, you can't put Mjolnir down on someone and hold them unless they are already down.

Comment: However, in the Battle on Titan in Avengers: Infinity War, Spiderman, Dr. Strange, Iron Man, Drax, and Mantis had him bound and at their mercies even with four of the six stones. Surely they could have done so again with him having none of the stones and Thor sneaking up and dropping the hammer on him :D

Comment: @noblerare thanos was alone on Titan fighting several opponants and was somewhat complacent about them, thinking himself too strong with the stones, Endgame thanos was not complacent at all, and was fighting against only 2, there is also the power object to consider, the same with Guns in real life, someone with a powerful weapon puts their strength in that weapon so thanos protected the gauntlet more than he probably should, thus allowing the opening, whereas Endgame Thanos didn't have that effectiing him

Comment: “Basically, you can't put Mjolnir down on someone and hold them unless they are already down”. That is not true. At the beginning of “Thor Ragnorok” Thor was fighting the dragon creature. The dragon was standing with Thor in its mouth. Thor dropped his hammer in the dragons mouth and the dragon fell to the ground, it was not down until Thor dropped the hammer.

Comment: So why didn't he do the same thing to Thanos?

Comment: @noblerare: Don't forget that Endgame Thanos **is not** Infinity War Thanos. He's shown to be more brutal and less... however you'd describe post-snap retirement Thanos.

Comment: @F1Krazy Thor did say, "Be a good boy, open wide." Thanos ignored him.